# Child window is closing automatically after parent window is launched in single sign-on (SSO) website using Edge

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, window-handles

Steps

1. Navigate to single sign-on webpage using Edge driver.
2. After passing url in main webpage after SSO login, child window will open.
3. On child window, a select button is clicked

When the script is run, it is not navigating to next screen after child window is clicked. Edge driver is closing child window automatically.

I am using 109.0.1518.78 version of Edge driver.

There is no issue with the code because I launched the website and clicked on child window is closing automatically.

Is there an issue with Edge driver? I tried using Selenium v4+.

Any idea why it's not navigating to the next screen after click in child window?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML, also properly formatted. A link to the page/site itself would be very helpful in this instance as well.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example code and consider describing in a more explicit way. It can help us locate the culprit.